# Batch Normalization makes Training Faster?

Tags: deep-learning, batch-normalization

I read everywhere that, in addition to improving performances regarding accuracy, "Batch Normalization makes Training Faster".

I probably misunderstand something (cause BN has been proven efficient more than once) but it seems king of unlogical to me.

Indeed, adding BN to a network, increases the number of parameters to learn : With BN comes "Scales" and "offset" parameters that are to learn. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization

How can the network train faster while having "more work to do" ?

(I hope my question is legitimate or at least not too stupid).

Thank you :)

Comment: I think I may be figured it out. Is it because batch normalization enables to use higher learning rate ? (I think that might be the answer to my question, can someone confirm it to me ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch normalization accelerates training by requiring less iterations to converge to a given loss value. This can be done by using higher learning rates, but with smaller learning rates you can still see an improvement. The paper shows this pretty clearly.

Using ReLU also has this effect when compared to a sigmoid activation, as shown in the original AlexNet paper (without BN).

Batch normalization also makes the optimization problem "easier", as minimizing the covariate shift avoid lots of plateaus where the loss stagnates or decreases slowly. It can still happen but it is much less frequent.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. You say it requires "less iterations to converge" but isn't each iteration longer to compute ?

Comment: @A.Piro Yes but the difference is usually negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization fixes the distributions of a lower layer activation to its next layer. The Scales and offset just "move" that distribution to a more effective position, but it is still a fixed distribution at every training step. This fixation means the parameters adjustment on the higher layer do not need to worry about the modification of parameters in the lower layer(s), which makes the training more efficient.